# is there a way to make images in a canvas loop and redraw themselves over and over again?

Tags: java

This is for a school assignment and this is what my teacher wrote:

Load an image to a JCanvas, and have it redraw itself multiple times, with the interval between each drawing getting shorter.  Once you have 100 images, clear the screen and start all over again.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
class MovingImages{
  
  public static void main(String[]args){
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Printing Images");
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JCanvas canvas = new JCanvas();
    frame.add(canvas);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int num = 100;
    BufferedImage image = canvas.loadImage("Earth.png");
    
    while(num<=100 && num>0){
      
      canvas.drawImage(image,x++,y++);
      
      num--;
     canvas.sleep(num);
     
     
   if (num==0){
                         
    canvas.clear();
  }
        
   }
  }
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is JCanvas?  None of your `import` statements import any such class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is doing exactly what you have described "redraw itself multiple times, with the interval between each drawing getting shorter".

The catch is that you need to reset the values when you reach 1 not 0, because your loop stops before it hits 0 because of  `&& num>0`:

```
//Change the number to 1 not 0:
if (num==1){           
    canvas.clear();

    //Make sure you reset the values otherwise it will not loop again:
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    num = 100;
}
```

Now it should loop as you need.